# Spline interpolation in matlab in order to predict value

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have the situation like on this image below:

[image]

This plot is the result of two vectors:

```
fi = [41.309180589278, 41.8087915220215, 42.8081880760916, ...
      43.8078181874395, 44.8076823745539, 45.8077808710707, 46.3079179803177]
m = [1.00047608139868, 1.00013712198767, 0.999680989440986, ...
     0.999524195487826, 0.999671686649694, 1.00012913666266, 1.00047608139868]
```

I need to get the values of `fi` where `m` is equal to 1. So approximately that will be 42.2 and 42.5.

I tried to do spline interpolation:

```
xq = [fi(1):0.25:fi(7)];
vq1 = interp1(fi,m,xq);
[fi1, fi2] = interp1(m, xq, 1)
```

But that is not working. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try `fzero`?

Comment: I tried now, like this:

    xq = [fi(1):0.25:fi(7)];
    vq1 = interp1(fi,m,xq);
    [F1,F2] = fzero(vq1,0)

And I get that the vq1 is the undefined function. How should I define function then? I looked here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html but nothing found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to find a zero crossing is to "turn the graph sideways", having `fi` be a function of `m`, and interpolate to find `m=0`. But `interp1` requires the `m` input to be monotonic, which this is not. In fact, this function has two different values for each `m`.

MATLAB knows the [`fzeros` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html), which finds a zero crossing of a function numerically. It requires a function as input. We can define an anonymous function using `interp1`, which returns `m-1` for any value of `x`. Here, `x` is defined by `fi` and `f(x)` by `m`:

```
fi = [41.309180589278, 41.8087915220215, 42.8081880760916, ...
      43.8078181874395, 44.8076823745539, 45.8077808710707, 46.3079179803177];
m = [1.00047608139868, 1.00013712198767, 0.999680989440986, ...
     0.999524195487826, 0.999671686649694, 1.00012913666266, 1.00047608139868];
fun = @(x)interp1(fi,m,x)-1;
x1 = fzero(fun,42)
x2 = fzero(fun,46)
```

This gives me:

```
x1 =  42.109
x2 =  45.525
```

Note that we needed to know the approximate locations for these two zeros. There is no easy way around this that I know of. If one knows that there are two zero crossings, and the general shape of the function, one can find the local minimum:

```
[~,fimin] = min(m);
fimin = fi(fimin);
```

and then find the zero crossings between each of the end points and the local minimum:

```
x1 = fzero(fun,[fi(1),fimin])
x2 = fzero(fun,[fimin,fi(end)])
```

Comment: For the initial guesses, you could use all pairs of points `fi(a)` and `fi(b)` where `a` and `b` are consecutive, with `sign(1-m(a)) = -sign(1-m(b))`, i.e. a crossing point. You can find these points in a vectorised way with something like `[false, sign(1-m(1:end-1))==-sign(1-m(2:end)]`. Then you can tackle similar problems with an unknown number of roots. You get the approximate locations for free from the indices of the crossing points.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an anonymous function so that you can pass additional arguments to interp1.

Try this

```
fi = [41.309180589278, 41.8087915220215, 42.8081880760916, ...
      43.8078181874395, 44.8076823745539, 45.8077808710707, 46.3079179803177];
m = [1.00047608139868, 1.00013712198767, 0.999680989440986, ...
     0.999524195487826, 0.999671686649694, 1.00012913666266, 1.00047608139868];

fzero(@(x) 1-interp1(fi,m,x), 43)
fzero(@(x) 1-interp1(fi,m,x), 45)
```

The 43 and 45 are the initialization for x for fzero.  You need to run the fzero twice to find the two solutions.